# Subclassing Uint8Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, subclassing, typedarray

I try to use Uint8Array to simulate a byte[] or uint8[].

[TypedArray.subarray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/subarray) creating a new view on the existing buffer,changes to the new object's contents will impact the original object and vice versa.

I always use it like this:

```js
let u = new Uint8Array(8) //'u' is 8 bytes
let a = u.subarray(4) //'a' is 4 bytes
console.log(a) // show [0,0,0,0], it is ok
```

but when I try to subclassing Uint8Array, subarray goes strange.

```js
class bytes extends Uint8Array {
  constructor(arg) {
    super(arg)
  }
}

let b = new bytes(8) //'b' is 8 bytes
let c = b.subarray(4) //'c' should be 4 bytes, but is 8 bytes
console.log(c) // show [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], ??????
```

I want to know what happened and how to fix it.

Comment: Interesting... Both on Chromium and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with how arguments are interpreted by the overloaded constructor.

This works correctly:

```js
class bytes extends Uint8Array {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
}

let b = new bytes(8);
let c = b.subarray(4);
console.log(c);
```

Comment: constructor(buffer, byteLength, byteOffset) {
        super(buffer, byteLength, byteOffset);}//it is ok